# Inserting text inside a circle in Python

Tags: python, graphics, turtle-graphics, finite-automata, state-machine

I am trying to write Python code for drawing a DFA. I am planning to use the turtle library. Are there any alternates? I can draw the nodes but am unsure about how to insert the state names inside the circles.
Can anyone please guide me? Below is my code so far.
Thanks!

```
import turtle

def draw_node(some_turtle):
    myTurtle.circle(50)
    turtle.getscreen().__root.mainloop()


def draw_design():

    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("teal")

    myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
    myTurtle.color("white")
    myTurtle.shape("turtle")
    myTurtle.speed(5)
    myTurtle.pensize(4)

    draw_node(myTurtle)

    window.exitonclick()

draw_design()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code seems to be a combination of lack of familiarity with the turtle library in particular and Python programming in general.  I wouldn't necessarily say that the turtle library is the best choice for what you want to do but it can do what your program aspires to achieve:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

RADIUS = 50

FONT_SIZE = 18

FONT = ("Arial", FONT_SIZE, "normal")

def draw_node(turtle, text, x, y):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x, y - RADIUS)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.circle(RADIUS)
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x, y - FONT_SIZE // 2)
    turtle.write(text, align="center", font=FONT)

def draw_design(turtle):

    turtle.color("white")
    turtle.pensize(4)

    draw_node(turtle, "S0", -100, 100)

    draw_node(turtle, "S1", 100, 100)

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("blue")

yertle = Turtle(shape="turtle")

draw_design(yertle)

yertle.home()

screen.exitonclick()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right about me being new to python. Thank you very much for your code; May I please know if turtle isn't the best choice, what are the alternates?

Comment: @Chica_Programmador, one alternative is to use the tkinter module upon which the turtle module is built.  It's more complicated than turtle but, just like turtle, you can build a set of functions that relate to your problem domain and then work with those in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot install *turtle* module in my environment, but I think that problem is in variable scopes.

**myTurtle** variable is not defined in global scope, so **myTurtle** from **draw_node** is different then **myTurtle** from **draw_design**.

In the other hand, function **draw_node** is correctly called with **myTurtle** as the input parameter, but in fact there is no use of that input inside **draw_node**.

Try to change that:

```
def draw_node(some_turtle):
    myTurtle.circle(50)
    turtle.getscreen().__root.mainloop()
```

to that:

```
def draw_node(some_turtle):
    some_turtle.circle(50)
    turtle.getscreen().__root.mainloop()
```